Generalizing Normality to Transcendental Extensions?
A standard definition for normal algebraic extensions is

An algebraic extension $L/k$ is normal if $\text{Hom}_{k\text{-}\mathsf{Alg}}(L, \Omega) \cong \text{Aut}_{k\text{-}\mathsf{Alg}}(L)$, where $\Omega$ is an algebraic closure.

I wonder if this may be extended to arbitrary extensions in the following fashion:

An extension $L/k$ is normal if for all $\Omega \supset L$, $\text{Hom}_{k\text{-}\mathsf{Alg}}(L, \Omega) \cong \text{Aut}_{k\text{-}\mathsf{Alg}}(L)$.

Is this a meaningful definition? Could it possibly hold for a transcendental extension. If so, what can we say about its algebraic and purely transcendental parts?

Let us flesh out the comment by Jyrki Lahtonen.
Consider an algebraic extension $L$ of $k(x)$, and take $\Omega$ to be the algebraic closure of $k(x,y)$. We have the obvious embedding $i\colon L\rightarrowtail\Omega$, inducing an injection $\mathrm{Aut}_k(L)\rightarrowtail\mathrm{Hom}_k(L,\Omega)$. In particular, $y$ is not in the image of any of the homomorphisms $L\to\Omega$ which factor through $i$.
However we also have the embedding $j\colon k(x)\rightarrowtail\Omega$ such that $x\mapsto y$. As $L/k(x)$ is algebraic and $\Omega$ is algebraically closed, this extends to an embedding $j\colon L\rightarrowtail\Omega$, and induces a different injection $\mathrm{Aut}_k(L)\rightarrowtail\mathrm{Hom}_k(L,\Omega)$ (since $y$ lies in the image of every homomorphism $L\rightarrowtail\Omega$ factoring through $j$).
This says that the requirement fails for every algebraic extension of $k(x)$.

It turned to be even simpler than I imagined. Good job.
